# Sench touch app xtype:list and xtype:button tap event delay for android device and iOS working fine

Tags: android, cordova, senchatouch-2.4

Android hybrid app using sencha touch(2.4.1) with Cordova(3.6.1) in application have issue xtype:list and xtype:button tap event fire after 300ms delay and app responding very slow and iOS working fine.

Any suggest me how to improve app perforce and tap event.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link with some solutions: 
[5 Ways to Prevent the 300ms Click Delay on Mobile Devices](http://www.sitepoint.com/5-ways-prevent-300ms-click-delay-mobile-devices/)

I personnaly used [Fast click](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) (presended in the 5th method) in several previous projects

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @DavidC , I was try with your solution but not possible to implement with our problem and existing code .